# Moving asparagus to a pot then back in the ground a few months later

Tags: transplanting, asparagus

There are three mature asparagus plants in our backyard, which we've been enjoying so far since we moved in a few months ago. Unfortunately, they are located in the exact spot where we'll soon be building a garage, and due to some other work we're doing in the yard, their new home won't be ready until September at the earliest.

What I'd like to do is dig them up and house them temporarily in large pots. Then in September we'll plant them in their new permanent home.

How likely are they to survive this process? What can I do to help ensure their survival? Am I better off just starting new asparagus plants?

I am in Madison, WI ([USDA plant hardiness zone 5a](https://planthardiness.ars.usda.gov/PHZMWeb/#)), and all locations (current, temporary, and future) are in full sun.

Answer (score 3):

This will probably not end well, for two reasons.

One is that asparagus grows very deep roots. A "mature" plant may have a root system going down 6 feet, and obviously you can't put the plant in a pot without severely damaging them.

If you are transplanting asparagus to somewhere else in a garden, the recommended times are either just before growth starts in spring, or just after it has ended in autumn - not right now, when it is in full growth.

Since you can't move a mature plant without reducing its root system to the size of an immature plant, to be honest you might just as well buy some new plants rather than try your luck at moving the old ones.

Comment: You may increase chances, if you move a lot of soil. Ask builders. Probably they need to remove part of soil. Possibly they could remove your asparagus in one shot with a caterpillar/trax. Then do not move it again until fall.